# MVC Redirect not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

Hi I AM using Database first approach in my MVC project. I have an action where I am calling Stored procedure when user clicks on Accept terms.

Here as soon as i calling this stored procedure, in my table it is storing current date and making **termsaccepted** field from false to true. It is working fine. I have condition like only when user accepted terms they can redirect to **Default** page. But even after calling stored procedure and updating date it is not redirecting to Default page.

And what I observed is, if i close and open my solution, then it is taking latest value stored in database and then it is redirecting to page which i need.

So how can i redirect to page as soon as value updated in my database without restarting Visual Studio ?

**My Action :**

```
public ActionResult Termspage()
    {
        TermsEntities updateterms = new TermsEntities();
        var ID = Session["userID"];


        if (ID != null)
        {

            updateterms.usp_UpdateUserTerms(Convert.ToInt32(ID), true);

            updateterms.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View();

        }
```

**My View :**

```
   <body>
   <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DefaultPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmIndex" }))
    {

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Accept Terms & Condition" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
 </div>
</body>
```

Here it's not redirecting to **Defaultpage** action even after details are updated in my database. But when i reopen my solution then it is redirecting to Defaultpage.

**Update :**

I tried to use redirecttoAction but when I use this I am getting **This webpage has redirect loop** error

Comment: There is no redirection in your code. You're only returning a `View`.

Comment: @Dai I tried redirecttoaction but i am getting webpage has redirect loop error.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`PostRedirectGet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method in MVC using  [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
public ActionResult Termspage()
{
  TermsEntities updateterms = new TermsEntities();
  var ID = Session["userID"];
   if (ID != null)
    {

        updateterms.usp_UpdateUserTerms(Convert.ToInt32(ID), true);

        updateterms.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Detail", new {id=ID})

    }
  }
```

Then

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{    
 // get record
  return View();
}
```

Comment: ha I forgot to mention. I tried this before only and when i use this i am getting **This web page has a redirect loop** error.

Comment: @Ajay, see I redirect to a different action. How come it will give you infinite loop?

Comment: Hi i am not able to use exactly as you told. If i use redirecttoaction inside if statement and tried to run, i am getting not all codepaths return valu. so even after i am using redirect, i am using return View() after if statement. and in detials you are passing id as parameter, do we need to pass this in my default page? I have in my default page redirecttoaction("pagename"), so can i pass like this? redirectoaction("pagename", id)?